# Count posts generated by loop wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, loops, foreach

On my category pages I am displaying each post as an li. I would like to assign each li an ID starting from 1 and counting up incrementally (i.e. if a category has 10 posts, the output is an ul with each li having an id of a number going 1 through 10. How would i achieve this?

**category.php:**

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying category pages.
 **/

get_header(); 
$counter = 0;?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php
                if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <header class="page-header">
                <?php
                    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                    the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
                ?>
                    </header><!-- .page-header -->
                        <div class="slider-cont">
                        <div class="slider-nav">
                            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div id="slider">
                        <ul class="slides">

            <?php
            /* Start the Loop */

            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                        $counter++;

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-category', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;?>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
        <div class="slider-nav next">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
            <?php the_posts_navigation();

        else :

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

        endif; ?>
                    </div><!-- .slider-cont -->
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

**And content-category.php:**

```
<?php
get_footer();

<li class="slide" id="post<?php $counter; ?>">
    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <header class="entry-header">
                    <h2><?php echo the_title();
                    if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?></h2>
                    <?php
                    endif; ?>
            </header><!-- .entry-header -->

            <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php echo the_excerpt();?>
                     <a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">Read More.</a>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </article><!-- #post-## -->
</li>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Before your loop add:

```
<? $counter = 0;?>
```

Then inside the loop before the li add:

```
<? $counter++;?>
```

and change the li to:

```
<li class="slide" id="post<?= $counter;?>">
```

Comment: That seemed to yield an ID of `"post1"` for all of them.

Comment: Can you post the entirety of what you're using? It's likely the placement of the first piece is in the wrong place (i.e. inside the loop instead of outside the loop).

Comment: I edited to show you the entirety of my code for this section

Comment: Drop $counter = 0 in just before:

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

Also, you need to echo out the $counter with <?=$counter;?>

Comment: That produced `<li class="slide" id="">`

Answer (score 0):

The `get_footer();` Method is placed wrong.

Move it from **content-category.php** to the end of the **category.php**